# Azure Cosmos DB query groups and sum totals

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB that contains "teams" with a field called `playerIds` (which is an array of id strings]

I need to be able to pass an array of player id and return the following:

```
[
{playerId: "qwerty", nTeams: 3},
{playerId: "6yhjk", nTeams: 0},
{playerId: "uytgyu", nTeams: 22}
]
```

I've been able to return ALL the teams the `playerIds` array are in
I've also been able to count ALL the teams ALL users in the database are in.

Any advice?

Example document:

```
[
    {
        teamName: "Wonder Mutt",
        id: "3456789",
        playerIds: [
          "uygduygf",
          "37nfyefyewf",
          "u298y2hf3f"]
    }
]
```

I have this, but it returns ALL the players in the database NOT JUST the ones in the array of ids

```
SELECT COUNT(r) as nTeams, r as Players FROM c JOIN r IN c.PlayerIds 
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT VALUE z FROM z in c.PlayerIds WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(
[
    "cdb5394b-401a-a752-50196bc99f23",
    "22b95c43-4466-82e5-24a2ae12faca",
    "1e62ed86-5a29bbae-0a791e578578",
    "df6679dd4f86-84e9-d44611c72451",
    "6074fa26-4842-8768-eaa23b89bdbd"
], z))
GROUP BY r
```

Comment: what is `nTeams`? How is this computed?

Comment: `nTeams` is a computed property. The number of teams that user is in . The user is within userIds[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind it skipping players that have no teams the following should work:

```sql
SELECT p AS playerId, COUNT(1) AS nTeams
FROM c
JOIN p IN c.playerIds
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS([ 'qwerty', '6yhjk', 'uygduygf' ], p)
GROUP BY p
```

This assumes that a player only appears once in a team.

Comment: thanks for that, I should have known this. Just one of those days...

Comment: How would you add additional filters like 'isDeleted' key/value pair or 'createdOn'?

Comment: Add it to your `WHERE`. As example: `AND (NOT IS_DEFINED(c.isDeleted) OR NOT c.isDeleted)`